# Django custom command to write a file without debug logging

Tags: python, django, redirect, stdout

I have a Django custom command to write csv file. In the code, I use `writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, lineterminator=os.linesep)`. When I run it with `python manage.py write_csv>sample.file`, it contains the file content and debug information, like

> `CDLL(libgeos_c.so.1)` Library path: 'libgeos_c.so.1' DLL: <CDLL
> 'libgeos_c.so.1', handle 5609f58baeb0 at 0x7f03df6b2c88> Trying
> `CDLL(libc.so.6)` Library path: 'libc.so.6' DLL: <CDLL 'libc.so.6',
> handle 7f03ea069450 at 0x7f03df6b2b70> System check identified some
> issues:

and also the part of logging: `logging.info('finish uploading')` is in the file.
Is there anything I can do to prevent those debug information write to file?

Answer (score 0):

You can set verbosity level of your command as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-verbosity)

```
 --verbosity {0,1,2,3}, -v {0,1,2,3}
```

> Specifies the amount of notification and debug information that a command should print to the
> console.
>
> - 0 means no output
> - 1 means normal output (default)
> - 2 means verbose output
> - 3 means very verbose output.